# setting TCP_QUICKACK with iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, latency

I'm writing a iOS chat app using MQTT protocol, and I'm using https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule for connecting to a broker service.

Right now I'm facing a latency issue and as I've investigated, it's due to the Nagle's algorithm and delay ACK (described here http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/nagledelayedack/ ).

Up til now, I'm able to disable Nagle's algorithm by setting TCP_NODELAY option. However I cannot set TCP_QUICKACK options, the compiler complains "*Use of undeclared identifier 'TCP_QUICKACK'*", and I don't know how to solve that.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TCP_QUICKACK is not available for iOS.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116340

> TCP_QUICKACK is not available on iOS.  If you'd like to see such support added in the future, I encourage you to file an [enhancement request](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) describing your requirements.
>
> P.S.: BSD Sockets is considered a compatibility API on iOS, and we encourage folks to use Network framework for low-level networking.  Enhancements like this are likely to show up there, and then be ported to the BSD Sockets API only if it's absolutely necessary.
>
> On the plus side, Network framework is a lot nicer to call from Swift.